# Connecting with different user to PDB in Oracle 12c

Tags: database-connection, oracle12c

is it possible to access multiple PDBs with multiple users?

Consider the scenario:

I am having two common user :- c##a and c##b
and pdb :- PDBTEST

I am facing problem :

When I connect with common user - c##b, i am not able to see table in PDBTEST created by logging with c##a.

Though, I have assigned rights in PDBTEST for both users c##a and c##b.

For common user c##b, is there any other way i can access PDBTEST?

Steps i am following :

Connect as sysdba

1> created two user c##a and c##b (container = ALL)

2> common role granted with all privileges : c##role (container = ALL)

3> Assigned c##role to both user : c##a and c##b (container = ALL)

4> Created PDB : PDBTEST

Altered session and set container = PDBTEST

5> Granted c##role to both user : c##a and c##b inside PDBTEST

6> connect with c##a (not as sysdba)

Altered session and set container = PDBTEST

7> Created Table and inserted record : TestTable

8> connecting with c##b (not as sysdba)

Altered session and set container = PDBTEST

I am not able to access table 'TestTable' after connect with c##b..

More, If i connect with c##a , i can access inserted records.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to qualify the table name (you did not specify the schema name). This is no different than a non-pdb database. If you define a synonym, you can make this work.

In addition set container is only provided for administration purposes and should never be used for user access. For user access you should create a dedicated service.

Comment: Yes it works with Synonyms, but when the same case arise for ~400 tables among 5-6 PDBs, and application have multiple user (like c#3a and c##b) with different roles and privileges, then how can i overcome such situation? Instead of setting container ,How can i create dedicated service?